# Random Crash in webrtc native library

Tags: android, crash, webrtc, webrtc-android, apprtc

I am getting this error randomly on some device when I request to close peerconnection on release build.
I have tried to set pro-guard rule for this but still getting below error.
Please help me on this .
My Proguard rules:

```
-keep class org.webrtc.**  { *; }
-keep class org.appspot.apprtc.**  { *; }
-keep class de.tavendo.autobahn.**  { *; }
-keep class org.abtollc.**  { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native <methods>; }
```

Fatal error in:

```
gen/sdk/android/generated_metrics_jni/../../../../../../../../usr/local/google/home/sakal/code/webrtc-aar-release/src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.h, line 94
    # last system error: 0
    # Check failed: !env->ExceptionCheck()
    #
```

Comment: check your logcat in verbose it'll help

Comment: I am getting the same error can you help with this? here is my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063434/webrtc-project-get-call-dissconnect-error-when-i-am-using-realtime-database-gett